# CSS vertical-align and inline-block issue

Tags: css

I am trying to create a 3 column layout where all 3 columns have the same height (height is not known in advance so I can't specify a hard-coded value for height) using the technique described here:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

I am changing the approach somewhat because I want to use "display: inline-block" instead of "float: left".  The code I am using is below.

The issue I am having is that the inline-block does not appear to be working properly as it is placing each of my 3 divs one under the other instead of side by side.  Can anyone explain to me why this is not working?

Here is my CSS:

```
#col1 {
    width:33.33333333%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#col2 {
    width:33.33333333%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#col3 {
    width:33.33333333%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 133.33333333%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#container3 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    background-color: green;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -33.33333333%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#container1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -33.33333333%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is my actual HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Sample Columns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container3">
        <div id="container2">
            <div id="container1">
                <div id="col1">
                    one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one  
                </div>
                <div id="col2">
                    two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two 
                </div>
                <div id="col3">
                    three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three 
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Width 33% will not work on all Browsers.  It must be a little less than 33%.  How much less depends on how the Browser calculates the width.  Generally 32% will work if there are no margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you explained the problem correctly.   The columns are not on top one another, they are side by side.  The text in col2 start where the col1 text ended. And same for col 3.

The reason it is not working is col2 and col3 margins extends to the left side of the page. 

The col2 margin cannot push through the text in col1 so it has to go under the text to reach the left side.  Same for col3 but additionally it cannot go through the col2 text either.  If you removed the text from col2 top of col3 would start aligned under col1 text.

To see for yourself in FireFox or Chrome.

- Put cursor over text in col2 and right click
- Choose Inspect Element.
- Move cursor in to the developer window and on to the the line of HTML
  for col2 and col3 in Elements Tab in Chrome or Inspector Tab in FireFox.
- You will need to expand the higher layer contents.

In the Browser window you will see the shaded box extending to the left side of the window.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't understand that the problem was my margin.  Your explanation is perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you do not want to use float.  inline-block does not work on all Browsers, like IE8.

You could use something like:

```
.col{margin:0 0 .3em .3em ;-webkit-column-count: 3;-moz-column-count: 3;-ms-column-count: 3;-o-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;}
```

If the contents of each column is dynamic.
You could use javaScript to even out the length of each column after onload event.

```
var max = 0;
var len = document.getElementById('col1').offsetHeight;
if (len > max)(max = len;}
len = document.getElementById('col2').offsetHeight;
if (len > max)(max = len;}
len = document.getElementById('col3').offsetHeight;
if (len > max)(max = len;}
document.getElementById('col1').style.height= (max+ 'px');
document.getElementById('col2').style.height= (max+ 'px');
document.getElementById('col3').style.height= (max+ 'px');
```

Comment: My main reason for not wanting to use float is academic.  I'm trying to understand why inline-block does not work in this situation.  I tried your suggestion of removing 66% and changing the widths.  This did not work.  Removing the 66% just causes the middle div to vanish while the first and last remain unchanged.  Changing the widths of the divs doesn't help either.

Comment: That's admirable and I respect that. BTW you can remove the display:inline-block and the rendering will not change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `width: 33.33%` while most browsers will ignore following numbers. Also `display: inline-block;` is known to add white-space between elements. There are several ways to fix this: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/